# Ruby on Rails where query with relations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to use where query with relationships.

How can I query using where with relations in this case?

This is model

```
User
  has_many :projects
  has_many :reasons, through: :projects

Project
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reasons

Reasons
  belongs_to :project
```

This is the codes which doesn't work

```
  # GET /reasons
  def index
    reasons     = current_user.reasons
    updated_at  = params[:updated_at]

    # Filter with updated_at for reloading from mobile app
    if updated_at.present?



      # This one doesn't work!!!!!!!!!!!!      
      reasons = reasons.includes(:projects).where("updated_at > ?", Time.at(updated_at.to_i))



    # Get all non deleted objects when logging in from mobile app
    else
      reasons = reasons.where(deleted: false)
    end

    render json: reasons
  end
```

---Update---

This is correct thanks to @AmitA.

```
reasons = reasons.joins(:project).where("projects.updated_at > ?", Time.at(updated_at.to_i))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to query all reasons whose projects have some constraints, you need to use `joins` instead of `includes`:

```
reasons = reasons.joins(:project).where("projects.updated_at > ?", Time.at(updated_at.to_i))
```

Note that when both `includes` and `joins` receive a symbol they look for **association** with that precise name. That's why you can't actually do `includes(:projects)`, but must do `includes(:project)` or `joins(:project)`.

Also note that the constraints on joined tables specified by `where` must refer to the **table name**, not the association name. That's why I used `projects.updated_at` (in plural) rather than anything else. In other words, when calling the `where` method you are in "SQL domain".

There is a difference between `includes` and `joins`. `includes` runs a separate query to load the dependents, and then populates them into the fetched active record objects. So:

```
reasons = Reason.where('id IN (1, 2, 3)').includes(:project)
```

Will do the following:

1. Run the query `SELECT * FROM reasons WHERE id IN (1,2,3)`, and construct the ActiveRecord objects `Reason` for each record.
2. Look into each reason fetched and extract its project_id. Let's say these are 11,12,13. Then run the query `SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id IN (11,12,13)` and construct the ActiveRecord objects `Project` for each record.
3. Pre-populate the `project` association of each `Reason` ActiveRecord object fetched in step 1.

The last step above means you can then safely do:

```
reasons.first.project
```

And no query will be initiated to fetch the project of the first reason. This is why `includes` is used to solve N+1 queries. However, note that no JOIN clauses happen in the SQLs - they are separate SQLs. So you cannot add SQL constraints when you use `includes`.

That's where `joins` comes in. It simply joins the tables so that you can add `where` constraints on the joined tables. However, it does not pre-populate the associations for you. In fact, `Reason.joins(:project)`, will never instantiate `Project` ActiveRecord objects.

If you want to do both `joins` and `includes`, you can use a third method called `eager_load`. You can read more about the differences [here](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/).

Comment: Pretty good explanation. I did just want to add on, it is possible to do a join using includes, and it doesn't always do an extra query to solve N + 1 queries. If you use includes and then add a nested condition in the where that filters based off the included table, you will get a left outer join. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer.  I also tried it with nesting relations, and some part worked, but some part didn't work.  Would you mind to see this related question?  @AmitA   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952179/ruby-on-rails-where-query-with-nesting-relations