# Ruby on Rails where query with nesting relations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I learned how to use where query with relations from this question.

[Ruby on Rails where query with relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949647/ruby-on-rails-where-query-with-relations)

However, I still can't make it right with this nesting case.
How can I make Summaries controllers index work?

Model

```
User
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reasons, through: :projects
  has_many :summaries, through: :projects, source: :reasons
  has_many :entries, through: :projects

Project
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :reasons
  has_many :entries, through: :reasons

Reasons
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :summaries, dependent: :destroy 

Summary
  belongs_to :reason

Entry
  belongs_to :reason
```

EntriesController

```
  # GET /entries
  def index
    entries     = current_user.entries
    updated_at  = params[:updated_at]

    # Filter with updated_at for reloading from mobile app
    if updated_at.present?

      # THIS WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      entries = entries.joins(:reason).where("reasons.updated_at > ?", Time.at(updated_at.to_i))

    # Get all non deleted objects when logging in from mobile app
    else
      entries = entries.where(deleted: false)
    end

    render json: entries
  end
```

SummariesController

```
  # GET /summaries
  def index
    summaries   = current_user.summaries
    updated_at  = params[:updated_at]

    # Filter with updated_at for reloading from mobile app
    if updated_at.present?



      #THIS DOES NOT WORK, what can I do?????
      summaries = summaries.joins(:reason).where("reasons.updated_at > ?", Time.at(updated_at.to_i))



    # Get all non deleted objects when logging in from mobile app
    else
      summaries = summaries.where(deleted: false)
    end

    render json: summaries
  end
```

@Error log on iOS

Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1481b9030 {Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"

@Error log on Heroku

[1m[36mUser Load (2.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m
2016-04-30T07:48:18.909397+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
2016-04-30T07:48:18.910250+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Association named 'reason' was not found on Reason; perhaps you misspelled it?):

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what's not working? What's the error you're getting on `summaries = summaries.joins(:reason).where("reasons.updated_at > ?", Time.at(updated_at.to_i))`?

Comment: I updated my question with error log, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're referencing `reasons` in a very haphazard way. `User` has_many `reasons` through `projects`, so why not go that route?

```
current_user.joins(:reasons).where(reasons.updated_at > ?", updated_at)
```

Secondly, and more specific to your error: your relation definition `has_many :summaries, through: :projects, source: :reasons` seems to be broken since `projects` don't have any `summaries`.

Consider adding a `has_many :summaries, through: :reasons` to your `Project` model, then use `has_many :summaries, through: :projects` in `User`.

Comment: Thank you very much!  It worked by updating models as you said!